# Android Camera App for taking photo over photo

Tags: android, photography, camera

Is there an Android camera app where I can choose a photo from my galery, give it a transparency percentage and then take a photo with the camera over that picture.

I have old photos from my city and want to take the same exact photo at the same place in the present.

Comment: Do you care about pricing?

Comment: Depends on the quality of the application and what it can do.

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Historypin](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.historypin.Historypin) – just not sure whether you'd like your photos "made public" (or whether the app also has a "private mode", as I'm not using it).

Comment: That Historypin was more that I was asking for. Very nice idea. Unfortunately it's very buggy in my Nexus5, it crashes all the time. 
But if you post that as an answer I'll accept your answer. Maybe they'll improve the app in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCamera allows setting a "Ghost Image". You can either use a preconfigured image, or set it to use the previously taken image.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking almost 7 years ago until now.
Thank you Lukas!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few apps that do this that I use, but my favorite "all-rounder" is called [Photo editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iudesk.android.photo.editor).

Just go to the option of text/image>image>change image then select the overlay photo then under settings (select the settings symbol) select that you want to show transparency and select the opacity you desire.

Comment: This does not look like you can take a picture over another one...

Comment: I'm not sure if you followed my instructions, but once you take the photo you can then superimpose another photo on top of it. Then you can change the opacity. Obviously it's not "real time" but it allows you to do the job.

Comment: As the previous comment states, this does not allow you to take a photo while viewing a semi transparent picture so you can line up a before and after style photo which is what the OP is asking for,